# Understanding the definition of specific heat in a gas dynamics context

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

**Background**

I am self-studying the book *Elements of Gasdynamics* by Liepmann and Roshko. In the introductory chapters on thermodynamics, the authors define the specific heat of a simple thermodynamic system (for example, gas in a piston/cylinder arrangement).

> A specific heat $c$ is defined by
> $$
> c=\frac{dq}{dT}
> $$
> i.e., $c$ is the heat needed to raise the temperature of a unit mass of the system by 1 degree. The value of $c$ depends on the process by which $q$ is added. For a simple system, the [specific internal] energy $e$ and the pressure $p$ depend only upon $v$ and $T$. Hence any reversible process can be plotted as a curve in a $v,T$ diagram. Of course, we could choose as well a $p,T$ or a $p,v$ diagram.

> **Thus, if we know the specific heat for two different processes, we know $c$ for all processes.** One usually chooses the specific heat at a constant volume $c_v$ and the specific heat at constant pressure $c_p$. Thus
> $$
> c_v =\left(\frac{dq}{dT}\right)_v\\
> c_p =\left(\frac{dq}{dT}\right)_p
> $$

The authors go on to use the first law $de=dq -pdv$ for a reversible process to determine $c_v=\left(\frac{de}{dT}\right)_v$.

**Question**

In short, my question is what does the bold sentence mean in the excerpt above? How is it that knowing the specific heat for two processes (constant volume and constant pressure) is enough for any arbitrary process?

Comment: The authors definitions of the specific heats are incorrect.

Comment: Maybe their definitions are different than the standard definitions, but I still would like to know the meaning of the bold sentence as it pertains to their definitions.

Comment: How did you go from $dT=0$ to a heat capacity of zero if $dT$ is in the denominator? We instead get an undefined quantity. And that's consistent with what we'd expect; since the internal energy of the ideal gas depends only on temperature, no amount of heating, however large, can increase the temperature at constant temperature or internal energy. (This is not the same as zero heating.) In addition, I don't see what that has to do with the bolded sentence. The authors don't claim that the heat capacity is always bracketed by the constant-volume and constant-pressure values. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree, it should be undefined for $dT=0$, that was just incorrect. I guess my question is why it's the case that we only need to know the specific heat for two types of processes (constant pressure or constant volume). What are other types of processes are there that would be relevant? And how do I show that for an arbitrary process, the dependence of temperature on heat addition can be expressed using only these two specific heats?